# How to have multiple columns with same formula that provide results in single cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

am very new to Excel. I am wondering if its possible to have multiple columns with same formula with results on 1 cell. For example, i opened multiple shops in Amazon, and Amazon charges 4,5%fees for every item sale. Is it possible to just highlight cells from Shope A to Shope D and multiply it with 4,5%?
[image]

I have tried but it will instead show each calculation for each column. On the Fees section itll show 5.2, and 0,0,0 for the subsequent cells. I hope you understand as English is not my main language. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to ask at our sibling site [su] instead; but please review their help pages and in particular formatting guidelines. A simple table would be vastly preferable over a (huge) image.

Answer (score 4):

Do you just want the sum of the fees for all the sales? In such a case you can use `SUM`, like so `=SUM((A2:D5)*E2)`. This achieves the same effect as manually summing each row individually (as shown in column F)

[image: Sum Example]

Edit: I read your question again, and I think maybe you are asking about absolute/relative references. You can read about it at the Microsoft support page [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

The reason why 4.5% is not dragging down is because the reference to the cell is not fixed. Adding a `$` in front of the row or column makes the reference row or column fixed, otherwise it remains relative. Here, since you want to apply 4.5% to everything, fix both the reference rows and columns by using `=SUM(A2:D2)*$E$2`

Comment: You beat me by 41 minutes :-) The clou is that empty cells are recognised as cells with value zero.

Comment: That's a good point, if the empty cells contain spaces like this" `"  "`, then there will be an error. In such a case for me, I would do a simple find and replace on the array, replacing `" "` with `""`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. However, you misunderstood my question. Probably because of how I phase it.
I don't mean total fees in a single cell. Since Shop A - Shop D has the same fees, I am wondering if it is possible to Select A2:D5 and multiply it 4,5%. So That means for G2, answer would be 0.2, and I can just drag it down to G5, with each answers automatically. Rather than manually typing =A2*4,5%, =B4*4,5%, C3*4,5% and D5*4,5%.

I hope you will understand, I tried my best to clarify. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Hmm OK, in that case do you just want the formula for column F? Is the 0.2 in your example just 0.225 rounded to the nearest decimal point? So my formula for cell F2 is `=SUM(A2:D2)*$E$2`. Then I drag it down. If you want to round it add `=ROUND(SUM(A2:D2)*$E$2,1)`

Comment: Using your cell F2 formula works! Just the way I wanted it to be. Thank you so much for your help! I may have overcomplicated it with the way I am explaining. Thank you for your patience and time!

Comment: No problem! A shortcut to changing the reference is "F4" on the keyboard. You can read about absolute/relative reference [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)